# Autofit long strings with EPPLus

Tags: c#, epplus

Using EPPLus library, I'm trying to autofit very long strings in xlsx cells this way:

```
worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
```

Rows: 1000

Columns: 10

For 2 columns, I'm expecting around 6000 character in each cell.
In this scenario, AutoFitColumns method generates the following exception:

> **Message**: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
>
> **StackTrace**:    at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(String text, Font font, SizeF
>   layoutArea, StringFormat stringFormat)    at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(String text, Font font, Int32
>   width, StringFormat format)    at
>   OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.AutoFitColumns(Double MinimumWidth,
>   Double MaximumWidth)    at
>   OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.AutoFitColumns()...

**EDIT**

Here is my full code:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    // Setup the first row with headers
    for (int j = 0; j < fields.Length; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[1, j + 1].Value = fields[j];
    }

    Color colFromHex = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B4B4B4");
    worksheet.Row(1).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    worksheet.Row(1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colFromHex);


    // Insert new rows
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
    {
        // this will return List<object>
        var properties =  elements[i].GetPatentProperties();
        for (int j = 0; j < properties.Count; j++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value = properties[j];
        }
    }

    // This will throw an exception for big number of elements: ~ 1000 element
    worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
    worksheet.Cells.Style.WrapText = true;

    //worksheet.Cells[autosize].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.CenterContinuous;
    package.Save();
}
```

Note that for the same list of elements, if I remove `worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();`, I will get my xlsx file without exception.

Is it possible to overcome this issue?

Comment: That should work - its really not that much data.  Maybe post more of your code.

Comment: @Ernie I added the full code

Comment: It looks like EPPlus is aware of the issue: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/445 There is a very good description of the issue there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting min and max col sizes?

```
ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns(10, 60);
```